# How to use Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable with vue2Leaflet?

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster, vue2leaflet

Can I use Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable with vue2Leaflet?
I have tried to include it and use it with a ref on my marker cluster like this : `this.$refs.cluster.disableClustering();`, but it gave the error "TypeError: this.$refs.cluster.disableClustering is not a function".

Comment: Where is the error printed? In console of browser or during compilation? And do you use TypeScript?

Comment: In the browser console yes. I dont use Typescript. I have tried to import it as the docs say, but webpack needs the module to have an export default in order for this to work, which is not the case. I also tried to append it with script tag from cdn to the page body after the component mounted. But it also did not work.

Comment: "_webpack needs the module to have an export default in order for this to work_": I am pretty sure it does not need, but could you show how you have tried ro import it? And providing a live reproduction example on StackBlitz or CodeSandbox would greatly help.